# How to create a child attribute table in doctrine 2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

How can I create a child attribute table through doctrine 2 (basically like a join table but without an entity on the other side).  Do I need to make a separate entity for it (I know if I do a ManyToMany with a join table it'll just create the join table in the db but does not create an Entity).

i.e.- I have work orders that can have a bunch of assigned work dates.  I want to be able to fill a table with those dates so

```
______________________
|      Orders        |
|____________________|
        id
         1
         2
         3
______________________
|     Order_Dates    |
|____________________|
order_id |   Date
   1     | 2019-01-01     
   1     | 2019-05-01     
   2     | 2019-01-01     
   2     | 2019-02-01     
   2     | 2019-03-01     
   3     | 2019-01-02     
   3     | 2019-01-05
```

So basically so far I have

```
class Orders
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dates = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * One Order has Many Dates
     */
    private $dates;

    public function getDates() : ArrayCollection
    {
        return $this->dates;
    }

    public function addDate(\DateTime $date): self
    {
        $this->dates->add($date);

        return $this;
    }

    public function setDates(ArrayCollection $dates): self
    {
        $this->dates = $dates;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I assume I need a @OneToMany or something but against I'm expecting the child table to be FILLED *FROM* the Order Entity, not a mapping.  Everything I look in the [doctrine association documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html) at here seems to expect some sort of mapping (perhaps I'm reading it wrong?)

Thanks in advance!

### Edit:

This is my controllers now:

**Orders**

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OrderDates", mappedBy="order", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=TRUE)
     */
    private $dates;

...

    public function getDates() : PersistentCollection
    {
        return $this->dates;
    }

    public function addDate(\DateTime $date): self
    {
        $orderDate = new OrderDates();
        $orderDate->setDate($date);
        $orderDate->setOrder($this);
        $this->dates[] = $orderDate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setDates(array $dates): self
    {
        foreach($dates as $date)
        {
            $this->addDate(new \DateTime($date));
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

**OrderDates**

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\OrderDatesRepository")
 */
class OrderDates
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Orders", inversedBy="dates")
     */
    private $order;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    public function setDate(\DateTimeInterface $date): self
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getOrder(): Orders
    {
        return $this->order;
    }

    public function setOrder(Orders $order): self
    {
        $this->order = $order;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **have** to create an entity for Order_Dates and use OneToMany annotation if you want an extra database table to be created for order dates. Doctrine does not support associations between entities handled by Doctrine and entities handled by another driver. Doctrine doesn't even support associations between entities handled by different entity managers.

**To sum it up:** You have to create a OrderDates entity and setup the association the traditional way.

**EDIT:** You should set up your association like this:

```
class Orders {
    // id and other fields here...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OrderDates", mappedBy="order", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=TRUE)
     */
    private $dates;

    public function addDate(\DateTime $date): self
    {
        $orderDate = new OrderDates();
        $orderDate->setDate($date);
        $orderDate->setOrder($this);
        $this->dates[] = $orderDate;

        return $this;
    }
}

class OrderDates {
    // id here...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Order", inversedBy="dates")
     */
    private $order;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
     */
    private $date;
    // setters and getters here
}
```

Comment: So I would need to create an OrderDates table, fill it with a bunch of dates and then create a join table mapping?

Comment: I will edit my answer to show how you should create the OrderDates entity.

Comment: How do you get the data back out of the database with this?  I tried

    public function getDates() : PersistentCollection
    {
        return $this->dates;
    }

but it just gives me an seemingly empty collection

Comment: Have you persisted the OrderDates entities successfully? Do these entries exist in your database?

Comment: Yes, I've successfulyl been able to persist to the database.  I updated my post to show the controllers

Comment: I guess that you simply want to use $orderDates = $order->getDates(); and then $orderDates->toArray() to get the order dates. It seems like a simple lazy hydration issue.

Comment: Ah, actually I figured it out. I was calling it wrong in twig (like a dummy).  Thanks a  bunch!